# How to make sure the parameters of function template are random access iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I am writing a function with has as parameter, an iterator to any type of data structure.

```
template<class Iterator>
void Foo(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
 ...
}
```

However, due to my algorithm, I must be sure that the iterator is a random access iterator. How can I redefine my function such as only Random Access Iterator can be used as parameter ?

I could use my iterator as a Random Access Iterator and so, the code will not (or may not ?) compile in other case. But I'm not sure that it is the most elegant solution.

Comment: Look up "concept" and "SFINAE".

Comment: You just use it like a Random Access Iterator and if it's not a Random Access Iterator then it won't compile.

Comment: You would be advised to name the type parameter `RandomAccessIterator`, so people (and eventually concepts) are clued in to the requirements

Answer (score 4):

Uncompiled code:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category, 
              std::random_access_iterator_tag>::value, 
              "Random-access iterators are required" );
```

The `iterator_traits<>::iterator_category` gives you what kind of iterator it is. Comparing it to `std::random_access_iterator_tag` tells you if it's a random access iterator.

Wrapping the whole thing in a `static_assert` gives you a compile-time error if the condition is not met - along with a nice error message.

Comment: If `ContiguousIterator`s ever get a tag, `std::is_base_of<std::random_access_iterator_tag, std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category>::value` would be needed